# Backbone.js very simple validate model not working - following webtuts tutorial

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am following [this tutorials on tutsplus.com](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validating-models/) and it seems incredibly straightforward but when I run `person.set('age', -27);` it is NOT returning false and is instead setting the property to the negative value. I looked at the [backbone documentation on validate](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) as well as some posts online and it seems like it should work? I know I will not be getting back the return string quite yet.

Here is my js which unless I keep missing something is exactly the same as the video:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 30,
    occupation: 'worker'
  },
  validate: function(attrs) {
    if ( attrs.age < 0 ) {
        return 'Age must be positive, stupid.';
    }
  },
  work: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' is working.';
  }
});
```

A read a few places that said not to pass `silent: true` and I don't think I am...at least not explicitly in my code..

Comment: Are you doing this: By default validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true} is passed.

Comment: Is the tutorial up to date with the latest Backbone? There have been changes in how validation works, see the [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

Comment: Thanks both of you. It appears he changed his intro vid to show downloading the latest version but the later videos are still a bit behind. The changelog said  `Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default upon construction or in Model#set, unless the {validate:true} option is passed. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @xat and @mu is too short, the issue was an outdated video - even though a few of the earlier videos were updated to the latest version. The changelog for 9.10 states:

`Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default upon construction or in Model#set, unless the {validate:true} option is passed.`

So I decided to pass `validate:true` and also tested with `Model#save` and each worked.

Thanks guys!